# Volatile keyword in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

In the OpenGL Wiki, it is write :

> The compiler normally is free to assume that values accessed through variables will only change after memory barriers or other synchronization. With this qualifier, the compiler assumes that the contents of the storage represented by the variable could be changed at any time.

Going that way, I understand that when you are using synchronization like memory barriers or atomic functions you do not need to use volatile variable.

However, when volatile variables are useful? In my understanding, it seems to never be useful... Or maybe if the host or another commands make a, update, but I do not see which kind of algorithm will do such things...

Comment: `volatile` variables will not get optimized (at least in perfect bug free world)

Comment: Yeah but what does it mean in glsl context?

Comment: You know when you start shading you usually prepare bunch of uniforms which are not yet fully used as intended. The **OpenGL** implementation might and usually will optimize them out and CPU side code will not find connections to them resulting usually in errors and seemingly weird behavior. But yes without globally shared variables or interrupts is not too much of use of them apart debugging and benchmarking.

Comment: Honnestly, I do not think it is only for this kind of purpose that volatile variable exist